# Wear hats on profile picture or over profile picture?

Tags: prepositions

In the hat season, while complimenting someone about their hats, do we say

> The hat looks good **on** your profile picture

Or

> The hat looks good **over** your profile picture

Both sound similar to me. Please advice the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific example

> The hat looks good **on** your profile picture

would be the one to use since clearly the hat is **placed** within the boundaries of the profile picture

> The hat looks good **over** your head **on** your profile picture
>   The hat looks good **on** your head **in** your profile picture

Would be longer ways of saying that the hat sitting on top of the user's head looks good

For the hat to be **over** the profile picture, it would need to be physically **above** the boundary of the picture even though technically the hat is placed **above** the picture in an **image-layering** sense

Comment: Hmm, Interesting. So If  fit the hat outside the profile picture it would be?

Comment: **Over**, **under**, **to the left**, **to the right** of the profile picture. **On the right side** of the profile picture would still be within the boundaries of the picture.

Comment: How long should I wait before I can offer a bounty?

Comment: I think you need to have a minimum number of points before you can offer a bounty. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Yep, On SO we get a note telling that so many days are left to set a bounty. Here there's no such notice. So I wanted to know if it is different here. (75 rep for bounty, have 118 so thought of giving you 50 :))

Comment: That's very kind of you, but more importantly, **please learn well**, and when you can and feel you are able to, **contribute and give back**. We are all here to help each other.

Comment: Yep. I joined here to get more insights into the language and help my GRE prep. I'll be lurking around for a few more days to get to know the etiquette of this community. Hopefully I'll meet you often. Cheers :)

Comment: @Peter So, " sth over sth else" and "sth on the top of sth" imply same meaning. do they ?

Comment: @Cardinal yes it can mean the same thing interms of **above** and **below**, **over** is ambiguous in whether two things are **adjacent** to each other and usually means **not touching**, **on top of** usually means **touching**

Comment: To BhargavRao - Bounties are used when you feel like your question hasn't gotten a good answer, and you therefore want it to get more attention. @Cardinal - _over_ usually means not touching (an umbrella goes _over_ your head; that bridge goes _over_ the river), but there are cases where the two can be used interchangeably, too (for example: put a new coat of paint _over/on top of_ the old one).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that *on* is a safe preposition to use. After all, in the same way we put paint **on** a canvas, we can superimpose an icon **on** a profile picture.

That said, *over* can be perfectly acceptable, too, particularly when the "hat" functions more like a mask than a hat.

Generally speaking, hats go **on** your head, and masks go **over** your face.

So, there's nothing wrong with saying either one, but which word works better might depend largely on how the hat looks, fits, and is designed to be worn. 
For example:

[image]  [image]

I might be inclined to say that the blue flight cap looks good **on** my profile picture (because of the way it sits atop the orange), but that the Darth Vader mask looks good **over** my profile picture (since it is worn over the front of the orange).

Even the preposition *in* might work, when the hat is used more like an adornment than as a hat or mask. For example, it wouldn't be incorrect to say that this Christmas tree works "in" my avatar picture quite well:

[image]

(Unless, of course, you think the tree looks ugly. In that case, you'd be lying – but your preposition choice would still be acceptable.)

Comment: Nice answer :) ... But why the half eaten orange? Competing with the apple logo?

Comment: @BhargavRao - :^) No, not competing – but the resemblance is not just a coincidence. Have you ever heard the expression _[comparing apples and oranges_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges)? My SE avatar was inspired by that idiom.

Comment: Haha, nice. Hadn't heard about that idiom before. Reading the link now. Ty. :)

Answer (score -1):

*over* suggest movement (like *we flew **over** Santiago*) or when you cover a big surface. In this case it's just a punctual thing so I think *on* fits best here because it's just *a part* of a surface.

Comment: -1 What do you mean by 'movement' or 'big surface'? Could you give some examples to flesh out your meaning? *My hat hangs over his hat*. *His hand was over the pickle*. Where is the movement or 'big surface'?

Comment: @GoDucks I said *over* works for a big surface since it doesn't fit in the context that the OP gave.

Comment: Where is the *big surface* in the two sentences in my last comment? I simply don't understand your statement.

Comment: This is a classic case of trying to limit the meaning of a preposition when the word is too versatile to do so. You can wear a mask over your face, for example, and that doesn't imply your face is "a big surface". Other examples where _over_ is frequently used, even on just part of a surface: _Put the pan [over the flame](https://www.google.com/search?q="over+the+flame"). Hair can fall down [over your shoulders](https://www.google.com/search?q="hair+over+her+shoulders"). And you can wear a scarf [over your neck](https://www.google.com/search?q="scarf+over+*+neck")._